# How to convert specific Google Spreadsheet to Excel?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

Dear 'Google APPS Script' Experts,

I need a script to convert a specific Google Spreadsheet and overwrite an Excel file (.xlsx) within Drive (same drive folder). I have a script to do this the other way around. I tried to change the script to make it work and searched on the internet to find a script but the ones I found did not work. I have no programming knowledge in this area so hope someone can help me with this.

The script to do this the other way around, many thanks to the script expert who shared this, looks like....

```js
function convertExceltoGoogleSpreadsheet(fileName) {
  var dstFileId = '1dL8MbCKdoWFcV8............etc';
  fileName = fileName || 'Conversie_Test.xlsx'; // excel_file_name.xlsx = name of specific Excel file
  var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Conversie_Test.xlsx').next();
  var fileId = excelFile.getId();
  var srcFileId = fileId; // file Id of Excel file

  Drive.Files.update({}, dstFileId, DriveApp.getFileById(srcFileId))
}
```

Hope someone can help me out on this.

Best regards,
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can use the export method of Drive to export a Sheet as an Excel file and insert it into Drive using the Advanced Drive Service.*

#### Prerequisites:

Make sure you have enabled the Advanced Drive service by going to `Resources > Advanced Google Services`, scrolling down to `Drive API` and while making sure that v2 is selected in the dropdown, clicking the slider on the right hand-side so that instead of 'off' it turns green and switches to 'on'.

#### Code:

```js
function convertSheetToXlsx() {
  var ssID = "<your-spreadsheet-id>";
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=";
  var exportMethod = "&exportFormat=xlsx";
  var parameters = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var fileAsBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + ssID + exportMethod, parameters).getBlob();

  fileAsBlob.setName(SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getName() + ".xlsx");

  var fileData = {
    title: SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getName() + ".xlsx",
    mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
  };

  Drive.Files.insert(fileData, fileAsBlob);
}
```

#### References:

- [Google Sheets API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api)
- [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)

Comment: Thanks Rafa for your suggestion. The goal is to replace an existing Excel file in the same Google Drive folder...

Comment: Hello Rafa, looks promising. I'm only getting this error > 'Missing} after property list. (line 8, file 'Code')'?

Comment: Updated my answer - needed to use a '+' instead of a ':' after Bearer, was a typo on my part. Should all work now!

Comment: Great, many thanks Rafa! One more question. How to replace/overwrite the existing Excel in a specific Drive folder? It saves in My Drive as new file but it needs to overwrite to existing destination. Small note: your ssID is visible in the code.

Comment: Glad to help! If it's been helpful please accept the answer so others in future know how to do this too. As far as replacing the old one goes - there's no direct way of doing that you'd have to make a call to get the ID of the old file and call `Drive.Files.delete("<old-file-id>")`. And thanks! It's a private file but I've removed it all the same.